# Not able to install boto packages using pip 8.1.1

Tags: python, pip, aws-cli, boto

I have installed python 2.7 and pip 8.1.1 available in the same package. I am trying to install boto and aws cli using pip. I am getting the below error.

[image: screenshot from Commandline]

Comment: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` then retry, assuming `python` is linked to python 2.7

Comment: Python2 is end of life by next month, by the way

Comment: Now I have uninstalled Python 2.7 and installed Python 3.7. when i run pip --version, I get the below error ```C:\Users\av360012>pip --version                   
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using  '"' ```

Comment: When I run pip command. I am getting the same error. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Can you try `python -m pip install boto` instead?

Comment: I have tried but getting below error 
```WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/boto/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement boto (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for boto```

Comment: Getting the same error while downloading any package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to rectify the error is to change the proxy in Browser. Once I changed proxy of the default browser, it started working. Hope this is helpful.